# How to access images in UIATablecell

Tags: ios, ui-automation

I'm trying to validate that an image is showing/hidden using `UIAutomation` on iOS7.

The problem that i'm running into is that `.cells()[0].images()` always return `[object UIAElementNil]` even though I can see my image.
I also tried calling `images()` on the main window, but no luck either.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in UI Automation. Table cells don't let you access anything inside, which is caused by the way UI Automation works an how the cell hierarchy looks like.

You could do some changes to your implementation and make your cell images accessible in UI Automation by using `UIAccessibilityContainer` methods. However, that's a bit complicated.

You can also inspect `value()`. UI Automation converts all cell content views into a string and sometimes it is possible to check content just by checking this one string.

If everything fails, just go for another testing framework. There are several open source & paid frameworks that are more robust and much more documented than UI Automation.