# iOS UI Automation. Not all elements are displayed when executing logElementTree

Tags: ios, element, ui-automation

I have the following hierarchy of UI Elements:

> -UIATableView
>
> ----UIATableCell
>
> --------UIAStaticText
>
> --------UIAButton

The third element in the `UIATableCell` should be 'loading indicator' which is dynamically appears on the screen, BUT it is not there. I use `.delay()` before executing `logElementTree`. I am sure that everything in the code is correct.
Anyone else encountered this problem?
Does it has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIATableCells for some reason will only show StaticTexts and the Button for the cell. I have the same issue in one of my apps when I try to verify that the cell contains an image. Until this gets fixed you'll have to find some other way of referencing it.

See here for a similar question

[How to access images in UIATablecell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432002/how-to-access-images-in-uiatablecell)

I believe this has something to do with the way the table cells are created in automation. The class reference for UIATableCell has this to say:

> Important: In certain test scenarios, particularly with new off-screen
>   table cell elements, UI Automation is unable to immediately derive a
>   label for an element, rendering that element inaccessible to your
>   script. To avoid resultant problems with automated tests, your
>   application should always set the accessibilityLabel property for new
>   table cell elements. See UIAccessibilityElement Class Reference for
>   more information.

EDIT: Just for the sake of clarity I'm not exactly sure that the above blurb outlines this problem as I have not been involved in that part of the problem, but it does show that the system for generating UIAElements is not 100% for TableCells.