# UIAutomation recording doesn't work properly with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-ui-automation

I have a simple app that shows table view with 3 cells.
1. First cell has only button.
2. Second cell has button and label.
3. Third cell has only label.

When recording with Xcode instruments, the code is not generated properly:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

//tap background of each cell
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[0].buttons()["Button"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[1].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[2].tap();

//tap button of each cell
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[0].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[1].tap();
//this cell has no button

//tap label of each cell
//this cell has no label
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.49, y:0.25}});
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.40, y:0.43}});
```

It seems like recorder doesn't recognize pressed view and inserts something else instead.

Is this bug in Xcode tools or behaviour somehow related to UIAccessibility?

Comment: what is the error ? which line is not getting executed ? , If it is "target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.49, y:0.25}});" then use "target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].logElementTree();" to find all the cells there name and value , once you have this you can use the position of cell to tap it and never use "tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.49, y:0.25}}" , it taps the point where x and y axis meet which is not perfect all the time

Comment: You probably already came across this answer elsewhere but I bet this is the same issue as my answer here discusses - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204855/ios-ui-automation-not-all-elements-are-displayed-when-executing-logelementtree/25317433#25317433 
Essentially because of the way table cells are created the automation code cannot access the child elements